# Alternative Math Font

Tags: front-end, fonts

Are there other fonts that can be used for mathematical symbols?

I have noticed, that choosing another font (via Stylesheet) does not change the math font (e.g. for greek symbols). Symbols will just stay the same most of the time. I suspect that MMA is just substituting missing symbols in the new font with the ones from "Times" (or an internal one, surely it is "Mathematica1").

Choosing "Courier" will result in different greek symbols, this is the only one I found.

Which fonts include the neccessary symbols?

Answer (score 10):

Following from Mr. Wizard's post, I was able to get Mathematica to substitute Greek letters with whatever font I want by editing `\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\UnicodeFontMapping.tr`. I first tried changing

```
Mathematica: (Mathematica1 Mathematica1Mono) Automatic
```

into

```
Mathematica: (DejaVuSans DejaVuSansMono) Automatic
```

which worked for changing the font, however it forced all of the symbols in Mathematica1 to be rendered with DejaVu - including things DejaVu obviously doesn't have like the line for a fraction and the \[Wolf] symbol.

So I undid that, and then just changed the Greek letters to reference font set 0 instead of 2, -2, or 4, which works so long as you use a font that supports a wide range of Greek letters.

```
0x0391      N       2       0x41        # \[CapitalAlpha]
0x0391      N       0       0x41        # \[CapitalAlpha]
```

I did this through the Sampi symbol, and now the Greek looks much better with any font. [Here's my file](https://gist.github.com/dmikalova/4964368) if you want to copy it.

Here's what it will look like if you do these changes:

[image: Mathematica Unicode changes]

The first two are what I want Mathematica to do - display all Greek in whatever font I say just like any other text. The Text cell is in DejaVuSans, and the Input cell is in DejaVuSans Mono Plain.

The next two are what happens if you change your Unicode Mapping but don't change the default font - for Text it's Times and Input it's Courier Bolded. Notice that they're both missing some of the fancier symbols.

Finally, I have the Mathematica1 and Mathematica1Mono fonts. If you do not change your Unicode Mapping, this is what you get, Mathematica1 for Plain text, and Mathematica1 for mono spaced text. Ignore that some of the symbols are wrong here, that's my own fault.

Answer (score 4):

Internally there are only two sets of Greek symbols: proportional and monospaced.  These reside in the `Mathematica1` and `Mathematica1Mono` font files.

These characters are mapped to these specific fonts in the configuration file `\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\UnicodeFontMapping.tr`.  Presumably any font with the appropriate glyphs could be used with the correct mapping but the result may not be pleasing as the spacing and alignment are likely to differ considerably.  Should you choose to edit the file it has some descriptive comments in the header, but there are a few things that may not be obvious.  The file starts like this:

```
@@resource UnicodeFontMapping
Mathematica: Times Automatic
Mathematica: (Times Courier) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica1 Mathematica1Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica2 Mathematica2Mono) Automatic
Mathematica: (Mathematica3 Mathematica3Mono) Automatic
```

Fonts are given identifiers based on the line on which they appear.  `Mathematica1` is on the third line after the `@@resource` header, and counting from zero it is therefore given the identifier `2`.  The file goes through 15 by default but I believe you an add additional fonts in this manner.

The letter alpha is mapped by this line:

```
0x03B1      N       -2      0x61        # \[Alpha]
```

I believe the fields are:

1. The Unicode code point used in the Notebook
2. A letter designating the type of character, e.g. (**N**)ormal, (**V**)ertical spanning, (**H**)orizontal spanning, and (**D**), used for Overscript and Underscript but the naming of which I cannot guess.
3. The identifier described above.  I have yet to determine the significance of the `-`.
4. The code point of the actual glyph within the font file.
5. A comment delimited by `#`, reminding of the default `FullForm` mapping.

Comment: The - sign indicates that we shouldn't be using the Mathematica fonts when we're *in* *Greece*.  The Mathematica fonts are just a nightmare if you actually want to communicate in Greek, but Unicode makes no distinction between mathematical and lingual uses of Greek (except for epsilon, which evolved into two separate characters...and don't think that didn't cause a stir back in the day when the Unicode committee screwed it up, then majorly broke backward compatibility to fix it).  I discovered recently that the "in-Greece" feature didn't seem to be working as expected on Mac v9, so YMMV.

Comment: This resource file is going to undergo a major overhaul in a future release, incidentally.  Unicode support in Mathematica mostly predates Unicode support in operating systems, and some things are going to be changing.  So don't expect this file format to be future-proofed.

Comment: @JohnFultz Thanks as always for the inside scoop.  Regarding the forthcoming changes will there still be a user configuration file like this, just in a different format?

Comment: @JohnFultz Is support for characters not in the basic multilingual plane (i.e. > FFFF) coming?  That would be very useful for working with text in non-Roman scripts.  I have a little Chinese character lookup tool that searches based on components and this was a problem (as the database I used has lots of > FFFF characters)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it'll be a resource with similar sorts of information.  When the time comes, I'll be happy to discuss the particulars.

Comment: @Szabolcs In the next major release of Mathematica, I anticipate there will be support for the multi-lingual plane characters in MathLink, but not in the kernel or FE.  It's a start, but probably not helpful for you.  Sorry.  The good news is that the infrastructure updates I've discussed here help to lay the foundation for multi-lingual plane support.

Comment: @JohnFultz Hi John, Sorry to jump in this thread but I was hoping you could take a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17967/misaligned-densityhistogram-distributionaxes-plotrange since I know you are associated with Wolfram and maybe could help with the bug fix?

Comment: @AimForClarity FYI, comments do not "bump" a post in the questions list.  Only the person you @ ping and the author of the post under which you comment (me) will be notified.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard, I was just trying to get JohnFultz 's attention since i dont see an e-mail or message option from 1 user to another.

Comment: It seems that @JohnFultz's predictions came true - as of v10.4 there no longer is a `UnicodeFontMapping.tr` file in the installation. Hopefully John can comment on what's changed, and how to achieve the functionality asked for in the question in more recent versions of Mathematica?