# Misaligned DensityHistogram, DistributionAxes & PlotRange

Tags: plotting, bugs, histograms

```
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0.5, 0.1], {10000, 2}];
DensityHistogram[data, PlotRange -> 1, Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"}]
```

The problem I have is that the histogram on the axes is not aligned with the density plot because of the PlotRange. I tried using Mathematica 8 and 9.  Can someone please help me fix this?

[image: Problem Graph]

Comment: Please try to post self contained code. Add one more statement to fill your data

Comment: Yes, please include code to fill `data` so this can be run and observed without additional effort.

Comment: fixed it so that it is :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error in version 8.0.0.

Comment: I definetly get it on 8.0.1.0  x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jesus from Mathematica, here are two workarounds:

```
data=RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0.5,0.1],{10000,2}];

Show[DensityHistogram[data, Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"}], PlotRange -> 1]
```

or

```
ReplaceAll[DensityHistogram[data,PlotRange->1,Method->{"DistributionAxes"->"Histogram"}, PerformanceGoal->"Speed"],{Inset[obj_,{x_,y_},{Left,Top},off_]:>Inset[obj,{Min[data[[All,1]]],y},{Left,Top},off],Inset[obj_,{x_,y_},{Right,Bottom},off_]:>Inset[obj,{x,Min[data[[All,2]]]},{Right,Bottom},off]}]
```

Answer (score 5):

This issue also arises in version 9. Possible workarounds include:

a) Removing the `PlotRange` option and letting *Mathematica* choose the plot range automatically.

```
data = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0.001, 
     0.001}, {{0.005, 0.0015}, {0.0015, 0.0040}}], {1000}];

DensityHistogram[data, Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"}, 
 ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

b) Using one of the other options for distribution axes, which do not suffer from this problem.

```
 DensityHistogram[data, PlotRange -> 0.35, 
 Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "BoxWhisker"}, ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

```
DensityHistogram[data, PlotRange -> 0.35, 
 Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> True}, ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a bug then?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch - I guess so.

Comment: Maybe if someone like @BrettChampion can confirm then it can be tagged as a bug.

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is that I need the histogram on the axrs and I need the Plot Range. I think it must be a bug.

Comment: I should point out that I really also want the whole distribution to be in its right place, ie the gaussian blob should have an offset it should NOT be centered on (0,0), but mathematica seems to recenter it after DensityHistogram. any thoughts on how I can move it? maybe using show