# How can I set default size for some characters

Tags: formatting

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> could adjust the size, but how to store the satisfactory size?

For example: Each time I type <kbd>|</kbd>, its size is (I assume) 12.

How to make its effect like adding `StyleBox["|", FontSize->18]`?

Comment: any problems with the question? some downvotes?

Comment: I don´t get the downvotes, too... seems somewhat undeserved, especially since no one commented.

Comment: @YvesKlett Agree, +1 to counter them :) Maybe they do not like the font size?

Comment: Well, typography is a highly controversial topic ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett I like typography with mathematica, and I wish more effort of wolfram in typography...

Comment: I don't have a font file in mind so I cannot post an answer with an example, but if you can find this glyph in a different font in an inherently larger size you could edit `UnicodeFontMapping.tr` as discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13196/121) to use your new glyph automatically.

Answer (score 5):

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
 InputAutoReplacements -> {"!!" -> StyleBox["\[NotVerticalBar]", 25]}]
```

Then just type !!

or use

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[],InputAliases -> {"!!" -> StyleBox["\[NotVerticalBar]", 25]}]
```

to type <kbd>Esc</kbd>!!<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: There is one imperfect thing: First input `!!` and then add `xx!! yy`,`xx,yy` will inherit the `FontSize->25`.

Comment: @HyperGroups, increasing font size through front end menu exhibits the same behavior, it's a feature of the frond end.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a comment but it is wrong habbit to put the answers there, if it is not what you like I will delete it:

```
newNV[x__] := Row[{x}, Style["\[NotVerticalBar]", 25]]

newNV[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

[image]

Comment: This is good for some programming generated formulas. Now I'm  typing formulas by hand and `Ctrl+9` this way. But this is also useful, so just leave it as one answer.

Comment: @HyperGroups I agree that @panda-34 's answer is closer to your needs so I've +1ed it. :) Bun none of this two is ideal. panda-34's solution do not affect `NotVerticalBar[]` for example.

Answer (score 2):

By forcing the character to have a certain font size you run into the problem that its **relative** size will be incorrect if the entire expression is subsequently styled to have a different font size.

Therefore, it would be better to scale the character with a `Magnification` factor instead of an absolute font size. If you're interested in typesetting, I would assume that the relevant formatting is really only needed for `TraditionalForm` output, so I would use the following:

```
Format[
  NotVerticalBar[x___], TraditionalForm] := 
 DisplayForm[
  RowBox[Riffle[ToBoxes /@ Flatten[{x}], 
    StyleBox["\[NotVerticalBar]", Magnification -> 2.5]]]]

TraditionalForm[Style[a^2 \[NotVerticalBar] b, FontSize -> 18]]
```

[image: small]

```
TraditionalForm[Style[a^2 \[NotVerticalBar] b, FontSize -> 24]]
```

[image: big]

If you want this to be in `StandardForm`, you'd have to replace `TraditionalForm` by `StandardForm` everywhere above, and the result would look like this:

```
Style[a^2 \[NotVerticalBar] b, FontSize -> 24]
```

[image: standard]

Comment: This is not suitable for direct manual entry in WYSIWYG style, it's more like Kuba's approach...