# How can I get proper Latin Modern Math (including Greek letters) within Mathematica?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to replicate the standard LaTeX fonts within Mathematica, and I am struggling to get it to work correctly, particularly with Greek letters.

More specifically, I have downloaded the Latin Modern Math font, and asking Mathematica to use that font family is at least vaguely successful at producing something that looks like TeX output. Thus, entering

```
text = Style["ωt=π", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]
```

will produce text like

[image: output]

on my system. This is definitely an improvement in terms of getting closer to the TeX output compared to the usual fare, but it's still not there: it needs to look like

[image: TeX output]

and both Greek letters are quite different. Is there a way to replicate the correct font within Mathematica?

(All of this, by the way, on v10.4 over Ubuntu 15.10.)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(13196)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13196/121), [(84968)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84968/121)

Comment: Have you tried MaTeX?  The spacing is not a feature of the font.  It's a feature of the typesetting engine.

Comment: @Szabolcs I did try MaTeX; I found it a bit unwieldy and I'm looking for other options. In any case, I find it really weird that this is so hard.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm having some trouble with both of those.  Re [(13196)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13196/), I can't find any `UnicodeFontMapping.tr` file at all.

Comment: Re [(84968)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84968), I can't replicate @Szabolcs's answer - I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6aGvG.png).

Comment: Well, then use "real math" in Mathematica to allow it to add the spacing on its own. `Style[TraditionalForm@HoldForm[\[Omega] t = \[Pi]], 
 FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"]`

Comment: re your last comment: make sure that (1) you have the right font installed (2) you are using the correct font name.  The font name may differ by platform.  I use OS X.  It works there.  I heard you need another name *for the same font* on Windows.

Comment: @Szabolcs That produces [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WQgYp.png).

Comment: BTW, what's wrong with MaTeX?  It's surely less unwieldy that all these font settings ...  Can you come to main chat?

Comment: Sure, I'm there now

Comment: The glyph system [changed in version 10](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54721/121) so I think my answer to the first referenced question isn't useful now. :-(